# Asp Webforms with Identity authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, asp.net-identity

I'm in the middle of the process of migrating my .NET 4.6 webforms app to use ASP Identity (it was using sql membership). I followed the migration guide on asp.net site [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity) in how to create the tables and classes and it all went well: no errors or lost data.
Problem is when I try to login, the find(user,pw) method returns null even though the user exists in the new identity table.

Below it's my login method (the rest of the code is the same as the guide):

```
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
        var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
        var user = userManager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text);

        if (user != null)
        {
            var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            var userIdentity = userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, userIdentity);
            Response.Redirect("~/Homepage.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            ShowMessage(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode("Erro ao efectuar o Login!"), MessageType.Error);
        }
```

If there's any other information you might need to help me I'll be happy to provide

Comment: I guess you are using same connectionstring on Identity and your project, in my case it was same, and I solved my problem with adding one more connectionstring for Identity

Comment: Check if Identity is successfully connecting to the database.

Comment: Is there any specific change that the web.config file needs to use Identity? Because i read dozens of tutorials but only a few actually mentioned the web.config changes (and most of them were just the connection string setting, no specifics at all)

Comment: Could you resolve the problem? If yes, could you share your experience? Do's and Don't's. I am in the middle of doing the same.